# SQL Loader error for opening log file

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created an external table :

```
CREATE TABLE XX_Lookup_EXT
(
LOOKUP_TYPE varchar2(200),
LOOKUP_CODE varchar2(200),
MEANING varchar2(200),
ENABLED_FLAG varchar2(10)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY INTF_DIR1
     ACCESS PARAMETERS 
       ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE SKIP 1
         NODISCARDFILE
         FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
         OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
         MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
         REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
            )
     LOCATION (INTF_DIR1:'LOOKUP_CODE.csv')
  )
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
NOPARALLEL
nomonitoring;
```

When I am querying this table it is giving me the following error :

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
error opening file /orabin/tst/test/XX_LOOKUP_EXT_30723.log
29913. 00000 -  "error in executing %s callout"
*Cause:    The execution of the specified callout caused an error.
*Action:   Examine the error messages take appropriate action.
```

I have tried everything out. Still I am getting this error.

Comment: How is the INTF_DIR1 directory defined? Does the operating system directory it points to exist on the database server (not client), and if so is it read/writable by the Oracle O/S user account?

Answer (score 0):

@alex poole is right. The `/orabin/tst/test/` directory must be local to the database and the database server account, usually 'oracle', needs read and write permissions within the directory.